Не подключается open VPN
Вот мой лог. Идет бесконечная загрузка и пере подключение
[Jun 9, 2024, 11:56:07] OpenVPN core 3.8.2connect3 win x86_64 64-bit OVPN-DCO built on Jan 31 2024 12:05:53
⏎[Jun 9, 2024, 11:56:07] Frame=512/2112/512 mssfix-ctrl=1250
⏎[Jun 9, 2024, 11:56:07] NOTE: This configuration contains options that were not used:
⏎[Jun 9, 2024, 11:56:07] Unsupported option (ignored)
⏎[Jun 9, 2024, 11:56:07] 4 [resolv-retry] [infinite]
⏎[Jun 9, 2024, 11:56:07] 8 [tun-mtu-extra] [32]
⏎[Jun 9, 2024, 11:56:07] 10 [persist-key]
⏎[Jun 9, 2024, 11:56:07] 11 [persist-tun]
⏎[Jun 9, 2024, 11:56:07] EVENT: RESOLVE ⏎[Jun 9, 2024, 11:56:07] Contacting 45.130.139.20:1194 via UDP
⏎[Jun 9, 2024, 11:56:07] EVENT: WAIT ⏎[Jun 9, 2024, 11:56:07] WinCommandAgent: transmitting bypass route to 45.130.139.20
{
    "host" : "45.130.139.20",
    "ipv6" : false
}

Что я должен поменять в файле у себя чтобы заработало?
